# IONIC CORS nightmare... Signed APKs still needs "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to run

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cors

I have written an app using Ionic. While debugging I used "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on the server. The origin is:"http://localhost:8100", and it worked fine.

Next I built an APK, signed it and installed it on the device. Turns out it does not work because the device origin is: "http://localhost:8080".

The problem is according to https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

> Running on a device What happens when you run ionic run?
>
> Your files for the app are copied to the device (or simulator). The
>   app runs, thus firing a browser on the phone/simulator to run the
>   files that were copied over, something like:
>   file://some/path/www/index.html. **Your origin will not exist, since you**
>   **are running off of a file:// URI; therefore, any request outwards will**
>   **not require a CORS request.**

So, Access-Control-Allow-Origin should not even be an issue on a release build running on an actual device, it is still being checked.

If I remove the Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the server I could never connect to it.

Anyone knows what is going on here? and what should I do?

Any advice is highly appreciated.

sincerely yours

Answer (score 0):

I never knew the correct solution, but in my case I managed to make a workaround.

I implemented an IHttpModule in the server. It checks for the origin and generate a header at runtime that allows that origin. Now i could directly connect to the site using the webbrowser, emulator, and mobile directly without having to change the origin on the server.